# Perturbed Circular Motion

Tags: classical-mechanics

A body is rotating in a circular orbit due to some central force. And by some how we perturb the system by introducing some radial velocity in the rotating  body.The  energy of the system will definitely changes due to change in the kinetic energy of the body. But what will happen to the  angular momentum of the body? Does it remains same or will have a new value?

Comment: Closely related, possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/250214/why-does-the-kinetic-energy-of-a-particle-moving-in-circular-motion-increase-whe?rq=1

Comment: To 'push', say a satellite, into a lower orbit, work needs to be done (centripetal force over the change in radius, integrated). That work done $W$ equals the increase in total kinetic energy $\Delta K$ of the orbit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give a rotating body additional radial velocity, the tangential velocity is unchanged.

Therefore, the product $\vec{L}=\vec{mv}\times \vec{r}$ is unchanged.

And this means the angular momentum is unchanged - even though the orbit changes (from circular to elliptical).